# Firestore - Adding additional documents without creating copies

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I've created a function that will add a "achievement" to a user as follows:

```
  const GiveAchievementTest = async () => {
    const achievements = firestore.collection("users").doc(user.uid).collection("achievements");
    const snapshot = await achievements.get();
    if (!snapshot.exists) {
      try {
        await achievements.add({
          title: 'Test Achievement',
          reward: 200,
          desc: 'Testing Function'
        });
        console.log('Gave Achievement');
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error in creating giving achievement to user', error);
      }
    }        
  }
```

Reading through the firebase documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data - it doesn't seem like they mention how to handle not creating copies of the same achievement because currently it auto-generates an id for the document.

How would one fix that issue? Would I need to set an ID so it can't create another one or would you run an if statement where it checks for  a match title etc?

Comment: I'm unclear what the problem is here.  It's entirely up to you to figure out how to avoid duplicates, based on whatever your definition of "duplicate" happens to be for these achivements.  Document IDs within a single collection are guaranteed to be unique within that collection - that is the only fact that Firestore can ensure for you.  Everything else is up to you.  As such, you might want to think carefully about how you work with these IDs.

Comment: The problem is should the function run again somehow then it would just create that document again. I want to avoid that from happening. But thanks will work on getting that sorted.

Comment: You will have to write code that dermines if "that document", by whatever method you use to determine its uniqueness, already exists in the collection.  Firestore cannot do that for you if the uniqueness is not determine entirely from the document's ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to make the Title unique on the achievements subcollection of the user collection.
If so, you can do like this.

```
const GiveAchievementTest = async () => {
    const title = "Test Achievement"
    const achievements = firestore.collection('users').doc(user.uid).collection('achievements').where('title','==', title);
    const snapshot = await achievements.get();
    if(snapshot.size > 0){
        snapshot.forEach(achievementDoc=>{
            const achievementId = achievementDoc.id;
            /// update data here 
            // firestore.collection('users').doc(user.uid).collection('achievements').doc(achievementId).update({...update data here...})
            /// or add new fields with merging existing data 
            // firestore.collection('users').doc(user.uid).collection('achievements').doc(achievementId).set({...new data here...},{merge: true})
        })
    }else {
        await firestore
          .collection('users')
          .doc(user.uid)
          .collection('achievements')
          .add({
              title: title,
              reward: 200,
              desc: 'Testing Function'
          })
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks bunbalhara! The .where('title','==', title); is what was needed thanks for the assist